# Store CSV data into separate objects according to row

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am trying to have my Python/Selenium script read a csv that has 5 columns, and a variable amount of rows, and then store column data for each row in a separate object.

Basically I want to be able to use the data from the CSV to use in functions being called later down in the script.

Disclaimer - I'm a complete noob who has only been learning Python 2 weeks, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

Here's my code so far:

```
def csv_read(file_name):
    open_file = open(file_name,encoding="utf-8-sig")
    reader = csv.reader(open_file)
    my_list = []
    for row in reader:
            my_list.append(myClass(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
```

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want to do here? Any issues you are facing?

Comment: I want to have access to the CSV data and use the column data for a variety of functions, and then move to the next row of data

Comment: Do you just need the column name for your use?

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many columns being accessed. You said that the CSV file contains 5 columns, `row[5]` is the 6th column because indexing starts at 0. Other than that, what is the problem?

It seems like it should work, i.e. `my_list` would be a list of `myClass` class instances. You can call the methods on those classes by iterating over `my_list`:

```
for x in my_list:
    x.some_method()
```

where `some_method()` is a method defined in `myClass`.

Or you can pass the instances into another function that processes them:

```
for x in my_list:
    some_function(x)
```